# cloudinary cloudinary.models.CloudinaryField add public_id to the field

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

Here is a simple model:

class Product(models.Model):

```
caption = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
description=models.TextField()
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
designNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.IntegerField()
stock = models.IntegerField()
parameters = models.ManyToManyField(ProductParameterValues)
image = cloudinary.models.CloudinaryField('image')
added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.designNumber + ":" + self.caption + ":" + self.supplier.name
```

I want to be able to have the image (cloudinary image) have a public id made up of the other params - like supplier.user.id and designNumber.

How do we do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version of the Python library you can inherit from CloudinaryField and determine the public_id (and the other upload parameter) from the model's attributes e.g.:

```
class MyCloudinaryField(CloudinaryField):
    def upload_options(self, model_instance):
       return {'public_id': model_instance.supplier.user.id + "-" + model_instance.designNumber}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to see a way to access the field's existing public_id during an edit operation. I looked through what was available on `self` and `model_instance`. Did I miss it? I want to ensure it keeps its existing public_id if it already has one.